# MySQL SELECT the PHP data without POSTing it Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress(last)

I try to Echo `SUM(feed)` from SQL table in the archive loop where all posts of specific category shown

```
<section category="category1">
...
<?php get_template_part( 'entry_category' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</section>
```

In my `entry_category` i've got basic HTML tags to output an article and my function to echo `SUM(feed)`

```
<article>...
<?php bankTotal(the_title);?>
</article>
```

And here is the function in my function.php

```
function bankTotal($bank_name){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT SUM(feed) FROM feeds_table WHERE bank_name='$bank_name'"));
print_r($result);
```

I understand that I Need to `$_POST` $bank_name to a function.
But is there a way to do so WITHOUT `$_POST` ? Something like `bankTotal($bank_name)`

I'l need to show `SUM(feed)` for each `<Article>...</article>` of a `<section>`

Is there a way to pass the `$bank_name` to a function without using ajax(`$_POST['bank_name'];`)?

SQL table looks like this:

```
bank_name | segment_name | feed |
---------------------------------
bank-A    | segmentB     | 12   |
bank-A    | segmentC     |  2   |
.................................
bank-X    | segmentA     | 32   |
```

***SOLVED(thanks to Seti) UPD: If you are trying to `ECHO` out `SUM(row)` do it like this

```
function bankTotal($bank_name){
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT SUM(feed) AS someTotal FROM feeds_table WHERE bank_name='$bank_name'", ARRAY_N));
foreach($result as $row){
echo "$row->someTotal";
}
}
```

Comment: <article>...
<?php bankTotal(get_the_title());?>
</article>
Also read a bit about $wpdb->prepare()  as you should use it to filter data.

Comment: You can submit the form or use ajax.  Those are your only choices.

Comment: Please supply the answer to what enabled this to start working for you. Will give insight to future readers

Comment: Im changing my comment to answer, so others can fast find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code part to

```
<article>
    ...
    <?php bankTotal(get_the_title());?>
</article>
```

`get_the_title()`  returns the title, while you used `the_title()` and that was printing title therefore not giving anything to the function;

Also read a bit about $wpdb->prepare() as you should use it to filter data